# How to remove sudo privileges from a user in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, root

I have root and one other user on my CentOS machine. With other user i can use sudo to perform most of the administrative tasks. Now, I want to take this privilege from this user, So that it can not use sudo anymore.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 3):

One way to achieve that on Centos is by performing the following 2 steps:

1. Firstly, you have to remove any mention of the aforementioned user
   (the one for which you do not want any sudo privileges) from the
   `/etc/sudoers` file or (if it exists) from any file under the
   `/etc/sudoers.d` path.
2. Secondly, you must remove the user from the wheel group in `/etc/group`.
3. (Optional) Finally reboot.

> e.g.:
>
> - For user centos `sudo vim /etc/sudoers` or `sudo vim /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users` and remove or comment something
>   like `centos ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` (save and quit afterwards).
> - Then `sudo vim /etc/group` and change the line `wheel:x:10:centos` to
>   `wheel:x:10:` (save and quit afterwards).
> - (Optional) Finally `sudo reboot`.

Hope that helps!